# How to add extra code to a vendor function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I need help on a specific issue. Using the package Lab404\Impersonate\ I allow certain users to impersonate a user in Laravel 9. However, when this happens, I want to log this with the Auditlog package with:

```
 AuditLog::create([
            'description'  => 'user:impersonate',
            'subject_id'   => $id ?? null,
            'subject_type' => sprintf('%s#%s', 'App\Models\User', $id) ?? null,
            'user_id'      => auth()->id() ?? null,
            'properties'   =>  null,
            'host'         => request()->ip() ?? null,
        ]);
```

I have located the ImpersonateController:

```
public function take(Request $request, $id, $guardName = null)
    {
        $guardName = $guardName ?? $this->manager->getDefaultSessionGuard();

        // Cannot impersonate yourself
        if ($id == $request->user()->getAuthIdentifier() && ($this->manager->getCurrentAuthGuardName() == $guardName)) {
            abort(403);
        }

        // Cannot impersonate again if you're already impersonate a user
        if ($this->manager->isImpersonating()) {
            abort(403);
        }

        if (!$request->user()->canImpersonate()) {
            abort(403);
        }

        $userToImpersonate = $this->manager->findUserById($id, $guardName);

        if ($userToImpersonate->canBeImpersonated()) {
            if ($this->manager->take($request->user(), $userToImpersonate, $guardName)) {
                $takeRedirect = $this->manager->getTakeRedirectTo();
                if ($takeRedirect !== 'back') {
                    return redirect()->to($takeRedirect);
                }
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

There I could add the code but this off course not the correct way to do this. I'm not sure what the correct way to proceed is? Should I override the take function, or is there a better way?

Comment: Create your own method that logs and then calls take()/impersonates someone?

Comment: Listen to the package's [events](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate#events)?

Comment: Create custom class and make it parent for your package class. Then override whichever method you need and customize it

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [listener](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events#defining-listeners) to the [laravel-impersonate#events](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate#events)
and make the log in the handle method of the listener:

```
public function handle(TakeImpersonation $event)
{
    // do log here
}
```